# XSLT processing with Xalan APi 2.7.1

Tags: java, xml, xslt-1.0

I have to do xsl transformations in which I will pass the sample input xml to finally achieved the final transformation xml , I have written the program using  java api of a transformer , can some body please advise how canI write the same so that it works with xalan api 2.7.1 also , below is the code with jaa which I need to convert it with xalan compatible

```
import javax.xml.transform.*;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class TestMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException, TransformerException {
        TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Source xslt = new StreamSource(new File("transform.xslt"));
        Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(xslt);

        Source text = new StreamSource(new File("input.xml"));
        transformer.transform(text, new StreamResult(new File("output.xml")));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The API you need to use for Xalan *is* the standard `javax.xml.transform` API, there's nothing to change.  If Xalan is on your application's classpath then

```
TransformerFactory.newInstance();
```

will create a Xalan transformer rather than using the Java built-in implementation (which is itself a fork of Xalan).  If you want to force a particular transformer implementation then use the two-argument form

```
TransformerFactory.newInstance("org.apache.xalan.processor.TransformerFactoryImpl", null);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..!! can you also please convert my example to xalan specific that will be a great help, Thanks in advance

Comment: @sonumkumar like I say, there's nothing to change - if Xalan is on your application's classpath then your current code will use it automatically.